# CreateCriteria, joining associations

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

How can I write the following SQL using CreateCriteria:

```
SELECT  sa_bec_matricula.*
FROM    sa_bec_matricula
        INNER JOIN sa_matricula ON sa_bec_matricula.sa_mtc_num = sa_matricula.sa_mtc_num
        INNER JOIN sa_periodo ON sa_matricula.sa_per_cod = sa_periodo.sa_per_cod
        INNER JOIN sa_tpo_beca ON sa_bec_matricula.sa_tpo_bec_cod = sa_tpo_beca.sa_tpo_bec_cod
WHERE   sa_periodo.sa_per_abi = 1
        AND sa_tpo_beca.sa_tpo_bec_gpr = 2
```

Attach the model.
[link text](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/image.php?358fbcf71a.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your models and how they are mapped to your tables as Criteria are in terms of properties on objects not tables in schemas.